# $resource Custom URL

Tags: angularjs, http

Is there any way for me to pass a dynamic URL with $resource

```
factory('httpService', function($resource) {
return $resource(URL, { id: '@_id' }, 
{
'update': { method:'PUT' },
}
}
});
```

with a call from controller:

```
Movies.get({ id: $scope.id }, 'http://localhost:8080/movies');
```

if yes then how?

Comment: For dynamic do you mean parameterizable, if so you can check documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource.             var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {

Comment: Not exactly, Instead of just sending parameters i was wondering if we can send the whole URL?

Comment: Can you try, i don't know if it will work. $resource(':url', { url: '@url' }) and use  url as a replace for whole URL